# How do I preserve dimension values in xarray when using isel?

Tags: python-3.x, python-xarray

**The setup:**

I have an xarray dataset with dimensions `x`,`y`,`t` called `foo`

the selection command

```
bar = foo.isel(t = 2)
```

selects a single slice along the `t` axis and stores the results in `bar`

**My Issue:**
`bar` only has dimensions `x`,`y`

I would like to use `t` after the selection for quick recombination of many slices

**Expectation:**
`bar` has dimensions `x`,`y`,`t`  (The same dimensions as its superset)

- Each individual slice of `foo` has an associated `t` coordinate value in a real world setting. An individual slice `bar` from `foo` should preserve that `t` coordinate so that if a dataset was split for whatever reason, it can be recombined in the future.
- Predictable/consistent behaviour regarding `sel`'s or `isel`'s treatment of dimension would mean less manual checking.

**Questions**

(1) The documentation references a `kwarg` called `**indexers_kwargs`. Is there more specific documentation on what is accepted under `**indexers_kwargs`? I'm having trouble finding the definitive list or a definition that makes sense. My hopes are that there may exist a `kwarg` used to preserve the `t` value when using `sel` or `isel`. Does such a thing exist?

(2) Currently the approach I'm considering is wrapping `isel` or `sel` with a function that can preserve dims with only one value. Would be much happier if it were natively supported. Can you imagine/propose an alternative workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current solutions that preserve dimensions:

**isel using list**

```
bar = foo.isel( t = [2] )
```

**isel using slice**

```
bar = foo.isel( t = slice(2, 2 + 1) )
```